# How to make classes in a loop have the same attribute

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a class which has an attribute and a method (amongst others such as **init** etc) like so:

```
Class Example(object):

    default_outputs = ['a','b','c']
    def add_outputs(self,list_of_outputs):
        return default_outputs + list_of_outputs
```

and then I have a loop which does something like this:

```
list_of_outputs = []

for file in filelist:
    object = Example(file) 
    object.add_outputs(['d','e'])
    list_of_outputs.append(object.get_output_of_interest_which_depends_on_outputs_added)
```

so as you can see, I have this add_outputs(['d','e']) call on every object in the loop - ideally what I'd want is for each object created in this specific loop to have these outputs already specified. Obviously I could add these as parameters to the init function to get something like. 
    object = Example(file,['d','e'])

but that is effectively the same thing and it won't work in conjunction with the other methods I have.

So in a way I guess I want a class which takes some parameters and returns another class. A class that makes a class. How can I do that in Python?

Comment: `add_outputs['d', 'e']` is **not** a call; it is an index operation on `add_outputs`. Did you mean `add_outputs('d', 'e')` perhaps?

Comment: *A class that makes a class*; why not a function?

Comment: Also, `add_outputs` doesn't actually modify anything, and you ignore its return value.

Comment: the add_outputs call modifies an attribute (I didn't write the full class out) which is used by other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass is one of options for you, for example:

```
Class ExampleWithDE(Example):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleWithDE, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_outputs['d','e']
```

and then in loop use this new class:

```
for file in filelist:
    object = ExampleWithDE(file)
    ...
```

Comment: I didn't think of subclassing. How stupid of me. Seems to be the simplest way.

Comment: If extra outputs are fixed and known in advance, that's indeed the simplest solution.

Comment: @1654183 I don't think it is needed to write ``super(ExampleWithDE, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`` . Just writing ``Example.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`` is enough in this case, isn't it ?

Comment: @ndpu I don't undertsand what you mean with "variant"

Comment: @eyquem you can use super or not in some cases, i mean i like to use super

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to focus on this part of your question:

> So in a way I guess I want a class which takes some parameters and returns another class. A class that makes a class. How can I do that in Python?

What you're looking after is something called the MOP, the Meta-Object Protocol, also known as reflection (kind of, not entirely true I guess). This protocol is a set of functions and datastructures that describe the object system itself to the programmer (so you have things like a Class object and so on).

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/14/python-metaclasses-by-example/

However you could also just inherit from a base class that does this kind of thing at initialization, like so:

```
Class ext(Example):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ext, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_outputs["d", "e"]
```

EDIT: Fixed some stuff and saw that the second part of my answer is already provided by someone else, sorry about that.

Comment: Wow. That's a fornight's worth of work for me right there. Thank you.

Comment: It's not necessarily so that this is the best way to do it, just so you know, but it sure is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically creating a class is nothing complicated:

```
def extends_example_with(outputs):
   class ExtendedExample(Example):
       default_outputs = Example.default_outputs + outputs

   return ExtentedExample

cls = extend_example_with([d, e])
for file in filelist:
  object = cls(file)
```

Comment: Extremely nice solution! Thank you, I think I will take that one.

Comment: Note that it's only useful if you need to dynamically create the class, ie if (in your example) `d` and `e` are not known beforehand (else a fixed subclass would do) AND you really want the "extra outputs" to be (part of) a class attribute (else passing them as optional argument would be the simplest solution).

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit 1

Wouldn't the following be what you want ?

```
class Example(object):
    default_outputs = ['a','b','c']
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
    @classmethod
    def add_outputs(cls,list_of_outputs):
        cls.used_output = cls.default_outputs + list_of_outputs
    def get_output_of_interest(self):
        return ''.join(self.x*y for y in self.used_output)

list_of_outputs = []
filelist = (1,3,6)
Example.add_outputs(['e','hy'])
for file in filelist:
    obj = Example(file)
    list_of_outputs.append(obj.get_output_of_interest())
print list_of_outputs

print '================'

list_of_outputs = []
filelist = (5,2)
Example.add_outputs(['d','G'])
for file in filelist:
    obj = Example(file)
    list_of_outputs.append(obj.get_output_of_interest())
print list_of_outputs
```

result

```
['abcehy', 'aaabbbccceeehyhyhy', 'aaaaaabbbbbbcccccceeeeeehyhyhyhyhyhy']
================
['aaaaabbbbbcccccdddddGGGGG', 'aabbccddGG']
```

Quite evidently, the codes of the `__init__` and `get_output_of_interest` methods are just defined in order to furnish me an executable code that shows that the class' attribute named `used_output` is set before each loop iteration.
Doing so, this attribute as well as the object `filelist` can be set before each loop iteration and the result obtained after the loop depends as well on the value of `filelist` as on this class attribute `used_output` without having to set it for each created object inside the loop.

You may be interested by this excerpt of the doc:

> A class instance has a namespace implemented as a dictionary which is
>   the first place in which attribute references are searched. When an
>   attribute is not found there, and the instance’s class has an
>   attribute by that name, the search continues with the class
>   attributes.
>   http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

#### Original answer

Your question is hazy because doing repeatedly an assignement to one unique identifier doesn't give you access to several objects but only to the last one created.

But first there are three problems with your code  that make me doubting that you tried to execute it:

- it is `class` , not `Class` in the definition of a class
- `Example(file)` produces an error since there is no `__init__` method to receive the argument
- using `object` as an identifier overrides the access to the fundamental builtin object named `object`

Now to show what I said at beginning:

```
class Example(object):
    default_outputs = ['a','b','c']
    def add_outputs(self,list_of_outputs):
        return default_outputs + list_of_outputs

filelist = (0,1,2,3,4,5)

for file in filelist:
    obj = Example()
    print 'id of obj :',id(obj)
```

result

```
id of obj : 18632816
id of obj : 18603984
id of obj : 18632816
id of obj : 18603984
id of obj : 18632816
id of obj : 18603984
```

If you then want to access to the first object created, how do you do ? , since the first object had identity 18632816 and using the identifier `obj` gives access to the object with identity 18603984 !

The fact that the identities are alternatevely 18632816 and 18603984 is due to the fact that when the identifier `obj` is reassigned, the former binding is destroyed and the former object is lost in the RAM, and the process then reuses the same portion of the RAM to create the new object reassigned to the same identifier.

The following code shows more clearly what really happens:

```
class Example(object):
    default_outputs = ['a','b','c']
    def add_outputs(self,list_of_outputs):
        return default_outputs + list_of_outputs

filelist = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

li = []

for file in filelist:
    obj = Example()
    li.append(obj)
    print 'id of obj :',id(obj)
```

result

```
id of obj : 18632816
id of obj : 18603984
id of obj : 18633680
id of obj : 18743632
id of obj : 18743504
id of obj : 18743664
id of obj : 18743696
id of obj : 18743728
<__main__.Example object at 0x011E01B0>
```

This time, access to each created object isn't lost because there's an access through the index of the list `li` .
But the object accessed with the identifier `obj` is the last created one, and only this one. 011E01B0 is the hexadecimal value of the adress==identity of the object accessed with `obj` , if you transform it in decimal value, you'll find 18743728

So what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: The code is hundreds of lines long. I just tried to give a minimal example of the relevant functions so you can get the gist of what's going on.

Comment: OK. That's what I thought about after having posted my answer. The problem of simplifying a problem is that it often becomes oversimplified to be really well understood. I still wonder what you want . I realize that you seem to have no need to keep access to all the created instance objects, only to the last one: am I right ?

Comment: No, I create an object in the loop and then call a method on that object. The output of that method depends on the parameters specified in the add_outputs call. But the add_outputs call is the same for all the objects, so I wondered if there was a way I could design the class to take that out of the loop. 

I agree that I've perhaps oversimplified and not written a good enough minimal example since quite a few people seem to have been a bit confused. I'll try harder next time.

Comment: OK. It seems to me that saying "to take that out of the loop" makes me understand. BTW I didn't mean that you wanted to use the last object after the  xection of the entire loop; I indeed undestood what you explained: at each turn of the loop, the created object is used to obtain deduced data, but after that it doesn't matter to keep the said used object.

Comment: However, something remains unclear for me: does the list ``['d','e']`` remains the same to be added to the default_output at each turn of the loop ? If so, wht not crafting a class ``Example`` that will create an object already having the right attribute . Either you don't have acces to the definition of the class and can't modify it, either the added list is varying from turn to turn during iteration.

Comment: @user1654183 I posted a solution that doesn't consist to create a new class for each list wanted to be added to the default_output (as do the answer of _bruno_ with a class factory and _ndpd_ with inheritance) but only to modify a class attribute of the lasting class

Comment: @1654183 Did you read my edit, please ? What do you think of it ?